# Is there any "leg bag" for traveling safely?

Tags: luggage, gear, security, terminology

I'm looking for "leg bag" for traveling where I can put my iPhone, money and documents? I need something I can wear under my jeans, to avoid to be pickpocketed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are typically called "leg wallet" or "leg safe", and you can find them by searching for that term in any store that sells travel accessories. I've also seen them in the travel accessories stand at airport shops.